Azure function app in NestJS is just showing one http trigger function
From my NestJS application on Azure, I just the main function. I cannot see all endpoints in my app. All endpoints are reachable as expected. I need to connect this function app to API Management. For now, the API management just sees one endpoint (main), because the app is not giving the APIM anything else.
Why is the function app just showing one http function? What should I change to get a list of all functions?
This is a screenshot of the Azure function:

and this is a screenshot of the function.json file:

In C#, it wasn't required to change the function.json file. It was able to recognise it automatically.
This the NestJS code for one of the endpoints:
Main.azure.ts
    export async function createApp(): Promise<INestApplication> {
    const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
     app.setGlobalPrefix('api');
     app.enableCors(corsOptions);

     app.use(json({ limit: '50mb' }));
     app.use(urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: '50mb' }));

     app.enableShutdownHooks();

     await app.init();
     return app;
    }


index.ts of main function:
import { Context, HttpRequest } from '@azure/functions';
import { AzureHttpAdapter } from '@nestjs/azure-func-http';
import { createApp } from 'src/main.azure';

function createPsuedoApp(createApp: () => Promise<any>): () => Promise<any> {
  return async (): Promise<any> => {
    const app = await createApp();
    const psuedoApp = {
      getHttpAdapter: () => {
        return {
          getInstance: () => {
            return (req: any, res: any) => {
              const done = req.context.done;
              req.context.done = (err?: string | Error, result?: any) => {
                res.writeHead();
                done(err, result);
              };
              app.getHttpAdapter().getInstance()(req, res);
            };
          },
        };
      },
    };
    return psuedoApp;
  };
}

export default function (context: any, req: HttpRequest): void {
  AzureHttpAdapter.handle(createPsuedoApp(createApp), context, req);
}

App Controller:

@Controller('APP')
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Get()
  getHelloWorldFromApp() {
    return 'Hello Wolrd';
  }
}


Can you please share your NextJs function code which contains the code for all the endpoints

I see, you only have one http trigger in your code

Thanks for your reply. Where do you mean it should be defined?
should i create for each endpoint a function.json file?
i appreciate for any tipps. Thanks,

You should add all the types of function in index.ts by using func new and select the function type from the template.


In order to add multiple triggers in the NestJS function, navigate to your root directory of your function and then execute func new command to add a new trigger. This will create a separate folder with index.ts and function.json file.




Post deployment, I can see two triggers in function app.



Or else you can add different routes to the same file as well but it will show you one main trigger in function app which will contain all different route in it.
A single function with two different routes.

import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Get()
  getHello(): string {
    return this.appService.getHello();
  }

  @Get('hello')
  getHelloMessage(): string {
    return this.appService.getHelloMessage();
  }
}

import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  getHello(): string {
    return 'Hello World!';
  }

  getHelloMessage(): string {
    return 'Hello from the second trigger!';
  }
}



For the 2nd route, you don't need to add any separate function.json file.

